# Attach a method to a module

Tags: ruby, methods, module, adapter

I have this piece of code:

```
module Encryption
  extend self

  def adapter
    return @adapter if @adapter
    self.adapter = :@adapter
    @adapter
  end


  def adapter=(adapter_name)
    case adapter_name
    when :@adapter
    require_relative  "#{adapter_name}"
   # @adapter = Encryption::Adapters.const_get("#{adapter_name.pascalize_string}")

    @adapter = Encryption::Adapters.const_get("#{adapter_name.pascalize_string}")
  else
    raise "Missing adapter #{adapter_name.pascalize_string}"
    end
    end

  def new(key)
    print key
    adapter.new(key)
  end

end
```

And I have a method:

```
def pascalize_string(string)
    return string if string !~ /_/ && string =~ /[A-Z]+.*/
    string.split('_').map { |part| part.capitalize }.join
  end
```

How should I attach it to the first code, so I can use `(@adapter = Encryption::Adapters.const_get("#{adapter_name**.pascalize_string**}")`.

I keep getting this error:

> C:/Users/Ian/Desktop/Alpha/encryption/adapters/adapter.rb:23:in
>       `adapter=': undefined method `pascalize_string' for :caesar:Symbol
>       (NoMethodError)

Comment: Readers: if you are unfamiliar with `extend self` within a module, here's an explanation. Since the receiver is `self` and `self #=>Encryption`, the statement's equivalent to `Encryption extend Encryption`. That adds module methods to the instance methods, allowing the former to be called on the module. For example: `module M; extend self; def m; end;
end; M.instance_methods(false) #=> :m; M.methods.include? :m #=> true; ` It's similar to defining methods as module methods directly (e.g., `def self.some_method..`), but that does not permit classes to mixin instance methods.

Answer (score 2):

Just define it inside the method.

```
module Encryption
  extend self

  def adapter
    return @adapter if @adapter
    self.adapter = :@adapter
    @adapter
  end

  def pascalize_string(string)
    return string if string !~ /_/ && string =~ /[A-Z]+.*/
    string.split('_').map { |part| part.capitalize }.join
  end

  def adapter=(adapter_name)
    case adapter_name
    when :@adapter
      require_relative adapter_name
      @adapter = Encryption::Adapters.const_get(pascalize_string(adapter_name))
    else
      raise "Missing adapter #{pascalize_string(adapter_name)}"
    end
  end

  def new(key)
    print key
    adapter.new(key)
  end

end
```

It should be called with

```
pascalize_string(string)
```

not

```
string.pascalize_string
```

because you are defining it into the module, not in the `String` module.

There are a few other strange things in your code, such as the use of `:@adapter`, but they are not relevant to the topic of this question hence I left them as they are.

Comment: now it's giving me this though

C:/Users/Ian/Desktop/Alpha/encryption/adapters/adapter.rb:13:in `pascalize_string': undefined method `split' for :caesar:Symbol (NoMethodError)
 from C:/Users/Ian/Desktop/Alpha/encryption/adapters/adapter.rb:24:in `adapter='
 from C:/Users/Ian/Desktop/Alpha/main.rb:32:in `<top (required)>'
 from -e:1:in `load'
 from -e:1:in `<main>'

Comment: As I said, `:@adapter` converts the adapter name to a `Symbol` but all your methods pretend it to be a `String`. I have no idea why you are doing that, therefore I did not change it.

Comment: To be honest with you - I have no idea ether. I was trying to attach an adapter to 2 classes. Spent too much time trying to understand how does pattern process works. Found one example, that was quite similar to what I need to do, but I still needed to change some code. Once again, new to ruby, so I know that my code looks way too dumb.